# React event click not working only on specific element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am attempting to implement a working demo into my React App and I'm running into a strange problem. I have some event listeners that fire some functions, but the click event is not being fired in one case, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I've verified the elements exist and the format is the same as the working elements.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
initEvents(){
  for (const [pos, item] of this.menuItems.entries()) {
    //working click event
    item.DOM.textwrap.addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate(pos));
    //not working
    item.DOM.link.addEventListener('click', () => this.showContent(pos));
    console.log(item.DOM.link); //Shows all link items
  }
}

navigate(pos){
  console.log("navigate"); 
}

showContent(pos){
  console.log("show content");
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <span className="menu__itemText">NAME 1</span>
      <span className="menu__itemLink">LINK</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also attempted to add an inline click event with no luck. I've verified the z-index is set above other elements to not interfere, but I am at a loss as to what to try next.

If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated to hear them!

Comment: You should be using react `onClick` instead of dom methods like `addEventListener`. Show what didn't work using that approach

Comment: It turned out to be a css rule preventing the event from firing. I agree it should be onClick, but it made no sense why the event listener worked for one element's click but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was due to a css rule on the "unclickable" element.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Was preventing the event from firing with either the listener or onClick events.